# How to do an equivalent of GROUP BY in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm querying a SQLite database for messages inside hourly intervals, where I am interested in one entry pr userid pr hour (this is now done successfully using the GROUP BY clause). To query the database for every hourly interval takes a fairly long time, so I was thinking I would save time if I only queried the database once without any time interval, then manipulating the resulting array (chunking it up in hour sized chunks). And thus accomplishing the same as my original method. But how can I do this?

```
for k in range(0,3000):
    start = 1398942000+k*60*60
    end = 1398942000+(k+1)*60*60
    cur.execute('SELECT userid, unixtime, latitude, longitude FROM table WHERE unixtime > {start} AND unixtime < {end} GROUP BY userid'.format(start = start, end = end))
```

This is my query as it is now. This works good, but takes a lot of time. Ideally it would look like this:

```
cur.execute('SELECT userid, unixtime latitude, longitude FROM message')
```

Then

```
* list = fetchall bla bla bla*
for k in range(0,137*24):
    start = 1398942000+k*60*60
    end = 1398942000+(k+1)*60*60
    thisHourInterval = list[:indextoClosestUnixTimeToEnd]
    list = list[indextoClosestUnixTimeToEnd:]
    *Only one entry pr id in thisHourInterval*
```

Or am I wrong when I think this will be a faster solution? The amount of data is fairly large, probably >4gig.

To be clear - I know how to get the data from the database, but I am seeking a *python* equivalent of Group BY and where unixtime> start and unixtime < end

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'GROUP BY' as opposed to 'group by' in your original query?

You should be able to utilize the full breadth of sql within these wrappers.

If you want to manipulate the data within python you need to get the data in memory in python.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my formatting fault. Yes I use GROUP BY and it works great, but I rather want to put the whole dataset in memory and work with it there, than querying the SQLite database that many times - but maybe just querying is the fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.execute('SELECT userid, unixtime, latitude, longitude FROM table WHERE 1=1')
d = {}
for line in cur.iterdump():
    index=(line[1]-1398942000)%3600 # line[1] might want to be line['unixtime']
    if((index in d) == False):
        d[index] = []
    d[index].append(line)
```

Are you not entertained?

Comment: Thank you for your effort, sorry if I was unclear, but I am unsure how I would "do something to each row" to accomplish the same as "group by" and "where unixtime>start and unixtime<end"  only in python.